# Get Source of Loaded URLs via Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension that needs to be able to analyze the source code of a specific HTML page and all the external Javascript and CSS files it loads **without loading them again via an XHR request** - that is, it will be analyzing the running copies loaded by the browser.

Is that possible? I know it's possible to analyze the source of a particular open tab, but while these Javascript files will be loaded by the browser, they obviously won't be occupying their own tab or window (only the HTML loading them will be.) Please help!

Comment: I suggest you start looking into the Developer's Console, since I think that does what you want, and it is written in plain HTML, CSS, and JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, there is no way to get the source of the resources without resorting to the [`chrome.experimental.devtools.resources`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/experimental.devtools.resources.html) APIs.

However, when the experimental APIs are enabled using the `--enable-experimental-extension-apis` switch, you can do the following to retrieve the source of each resource:

```
chrome.experimental.devtools.resources.onFinished.addListener(function(resource) {
  resource.getContent(function(content, encoding) {
    if(encoding !== 'base64') {
      alert(content);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but is there a way that would work on all Chrome browsers? This plugin needs to be usable by everyone.

Comment: @kaepora: Until that particular API gets released from experimental, unfortunately not. However, you can detect if the APIs are unavailable and instruct the users on how to enable them.